# For mailchimp can the Unsubscribe merge tag link to a custom form instead of the MailChimp hosted Unsubscribe form?

Tags: mailchimp

Im required by law to have a link in all emails that allow an opt-out. It seems that link thats a *|UNSUB|* merge tag links directly to the MailChimp Hosted Unsubscribe Form. This isn't helpful as I want to be able to update my own external  database if someone unsubscribes. I was wondering if there is a way to host to own unsubscribe form. Or if thats not possible to have the Mailchimp Hosted Unsubscribe Form somehow update my external database.
Thanks./

Answer (score 2):

I haven't found a way to customize the `*|UNSUB|*` tag to point to your own server. But MailChimp has an API, or rather webhooks, that can talk to your server everytime an unsubscribe (or other event occurs). Go to your list, click `Settings` and choose `Webhooks` and enter the URL to your server that will be receiving the data that is sent in a `POST`. Here is an example of what is POST'ed for the `unsubscribe` event/type:

```
array (
    'type' => 'unsubscribe',
    'fired_at' => '2016-11-29 17:25:47',
    'data' => 
    array (
        'action' => 'unsub',
        'reason' => 'manual',
        'id' => '1788964578',
        'email' => 'john.doe@sample.com',
        'email_type' => 'html',
        'ip_opt' => '166.136.10.51',
        'web_id' => '178654877',
        'merges' => 
        array (
            'EMAIL' => 'john.doe@sample.com',
            'FNAME' => 'John',
            'LNAME' => 'Doe',
            'INTERESTS' => '',
            'GROUPINGS' => 
            array (
                0 => 
                array (
                    'id' => '84611',
                    'name' => 'Public categories',
                    'groups' => '',
                ),
            ),
        ),
        'list_id' => 'f633681b5d',
    ),
)
```